# Streamlit - SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread

Tags: python, sqlite, streamlit

I'm using [Streamlit](https://docs.streamlit.io/en/latest/index.html) as my data manipulating and visualization framework.

Following the docs on [advanced caching with Streamlit](https://docs.streamlit.io/en/latest/advanced_caching.html), as to how create database connections and pass them along other functions, I'm using `sqlite3` and trying to create one connection at run and the pass the 'cursor', by doing:

```
import streamlit as st

# create database connection
@st.cache(allow_output_mutation=True)
def get_database_connection():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('collect/Data/fpl.db')
    c = conn.cursor()   
    return c
```

Here I try to pass my connection id via `hash_funcs`, returning the cursor created:

```
# pass connections around
@st.cache(allow_output_mutation=True, hash_funcs={sqlite3.Cursor:id})
def get_teams_basic(c):
    df_teams = sql('SELECT * FROM TeamsBasic', c)
    return df_teams

@st.cache(allow_output_mutation=True, hash_funcs={sqlite3.Cursor:id})
def get_players_basic(c):   
    df_player_basic = sql('SELECT * FROM PlayersBasic', c)
    return df_player_basic

# and so on...
```

---

This is my `sql()`:

```
def sql(query, cursor):
    '''
    Takes an SQL query string, and outputs a
    dataframe representation of the query result.
    '''
    # Execute the sql query
    cursor.execute(query)

    # Get the query into a dataframe and set columns
    df_temp = pd.DataFrame(cursor.fetchall())
    df_temp.columns = [x[0] for x in cursor.description]

    # Set the sql id as the dataframe index
    index_column = df_temp.columns[0]
    df_temp.set_index(index_column, drop=True, inplace=True)

    return df_temp
```

---

Then, at `main()`, I instantiate the database connection and pass the cursor along to my functions:

```
def main():
    c = get_database_connection()
    teams(c)
    players(c)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

But when code reaches the second connection, `players()` I get the following error:

```
ProgrammingError: SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread. The object was created in thread id 123145444151296 and this is thread id 123145454661632.
```

Traceback:

```
File "/Users/me/anaconda2/envs/data_science/lib/python3.7/site-packages/streamlit/ScriptRunner.py", line 322, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "/Volumes/Dados/Documents/Code/Apps/app.py", line 280, in <module>
    main()
File "/Volumes/Dados/Documents/Code/Apps/app.py", line 273, in main
    managers(c)
File "/Volumes/Dados/Documents/Code/Apps/app.py", line 149, in managers
    df_players = get_players_basic(c)
File "/Users/me/anaconda2/envs/data_science/lib/python3.7/site-packages/streamlit/caching.py", line 594, in wrapped_func
    return get_or_create_cached_value()
File "/Users/me/anaconda2/envs/data_science/lib/python3.7/site-packages/streamlit/caching.py", line 578, in get_or_create_cached_value
    return_value = func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Volumes/Dados/Documents/Code/Apps/app.py", line 64, in get_players_basic
    df_player_basic = sql('SELECT * FROM PlayersBasic', c)
File "/Volumes/Dados/Documents/Code/Apps/collect/PythonFunctions/sqlfunctions.py", line 111, in sql
    cursor.execute(query)
```

---

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if you are still working on this problem, but if you are I found a discussion thread on this topic that might be of use.  I will be trying it out on one of my projects soon.

https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/prediction-analysis-and-creating-a-database/3504